# Why does clang-tidy say vsnprintf has an uninitialized va_list argument?

Tags: c, variadic-functions, clang-tidy

In the following function, I initialize `args`, use them in the call to `va_start`, and then call `va_end`.

The code looks right to me, but clang-tidy gives a warning:

`tmp2.c:7:11: error: Function 'vsnprintf' is called with an uninitialized va_list argument [clang-analyzer-valist.Uninitialized,-warnings-as-errors]
    len = vsnprintf((void*)0, 0, format, args);`

```
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int f(char *format, ...) {
    int len;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    len = vsnprintf((void*)0, 0, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    return len;
}
```

Even more strangely, this only occurs when I lint multiple files at a time, so `clang-tidy tmp2.c` does not give a warning, but `clang-tidy tmp2.c tmp2.c` does!

Is this a problem with my code or with clang-tidy? I am using LLVM version 7.0.0, but the warning also occurs with 8.0.0.

Comment: It's a clang-tidy bug. Not sure what number it is, but I can look it up later.

Comment: looks like https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41311

Comment: The `(void *)` cast isn’t needed and is really counterproductive.

Comment: @JoshuaNelson, JL2210: That should be an answer, no?

Comment: If JL wants to make it an answer, I'll mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug in `clang-tidy`. It's most similar to [this bug](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41311), which you have apparently seen already.

Also, from a note [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58672959/why-does-clang-tidy-say-vsnprintf-has-an-uninitialized-va-list-argument#comment103648356_58672959), you don't have to cast `0` to `(void *)`. The cast is already implicit.

Comment: The bugzilla bug was moved here https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/40656